# How do I remove a URL of and old site from my AdSense application so I can now apply with a new site?

Tags: google-adsense

About four years ago, when I was using blogger.com for as my personal blog. I had tried to activate AdSense for the website http://example.blogspot.com which wasn't approved. I didn't try again and forgot about the AdSense. Years later, I deleted the blog.

Now, I have a website that I'd like to run AdSense but I can't because my AdSense account still wants me to fix issues with my website which doesn't exist anymore. And doesn't provide an option to change the URL of my new website.

How do I remove the old website example.blogspot.com so I can run AdSense on my new website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, go to your [Google Dashboard](https://myaccount.google.com/dashboard), delete the payment profile attached to the Adsense and then the adsense account data. Proceed with caution if you have an existing or verified adsense account.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the domain on an AdSense application.   Your only option is to start a new application from a different Google account and Gmail address.

This has been asked numerous times in the Google Product Forums and the answer is always the same there:

- [My account disapproved due to .TK domain now I have .Com domain and need to change Domain in application](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/uyQ2OTlTxWQ)
- [My domain expired before getting approved. I have new domain but cant update to adsense application?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/eCctknc01pI)
- [Change AdSense application from Blog site to YouTube Channel](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/K9nPRQxHDpE)
- [I want to change my website to a different one to get my application approved](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/hPBT6z_dlnc)
- [application refused but put wrong domain in! - can't seem to change the domain when re-applying?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/Y3RXV9qSQ0E)
- [I need to change the domain name on my application and it will not allow me](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/oDI-5rb1gwg)
- [How change domain for application when rejected?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/yjaBZKXeq5M)
- [How can change website's domain name while submitting the application?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/hCjmKFlYoRU)
- [How to change domain in google adsence application?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/dACmw6d5rtg)
- [AND MANY MORE...](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/adsense/application$20domain$20change)