# Cancel or go a step back in Google AdSense registration?

Tags: google-adsense

I registered for Google AdSense about a week ago. On the page asking me for my country, I accidentally selected the wrong one. Then it asked me for my address and stuff like that in the wrongly chosen country. There was no go-back, either a "cancel registration" button.

I watched a video on YouTube on how to delete your account. I understood that I have to go to settings and delete my account from there. The configuration option in the navigation was disabled. Screenshot:

[image: Disabled navigation items]

The thing I did:
I randomly filled up the fields, hoping I'll be able to access the settings tab after I complete the registration and then delete my account and start again. And what happened? Now I see this message:

[image: "We're reviewing your site"]

Comment: That may have been a big mistake.   You can't change the URL in an already submitted application, or apply with a different URL from the same account: [How do I remove a URL of and old site from my AdSense application so I can now apply with a new site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107929/how-do-i-remove-a-url-of-and-old-site-from-my-adsense-application-so-i-can-now-a)

Comment: The URL is correct; the country is my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, According to [this article](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense/fmaoopuWH-g) you can't really do much until Google 'Reviews' your account:

> Unfortunately, there isn't anything you can do until Google has processed your application.

You likely set off some sort of security measure after filling out fields randomly.